# Zybooks - python sphere volume challenge

Tags: python

Scenario: Given sphere_radius and pi, compute the volume of a sphere and assign to sphere_volume. Volume of sphere = (4.0 / 3.0) π r^3

Sample output with input: 1.0
Sphere volume: 4.19

---

```
pi = 3.14159
sphere_volume = 0.0

sphere_radius = float(input())
```

''' Your solution goes here '''

```
sphere_volume = (4.0/3.0) * pi * sphere_radius

print('Sphere volume: {:.2f}'.format(sphere_volume))
```

---

Test Results:

(Correct) Testing volume with input: 1.0
Your output
Sphere volume: 4.19

(Incorrect)  Testing volume with input: 5.5
Output differs. See highlights below.
Your output
Sphere volume: 23.04
Expected output
Sphere volume: 696.91

---

I'm getting the 1st half of the tests complete but when it runs the code again, it fails the 2nd portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cube radius value in the formula:

```
pi = 3.14159 
sphere_volume = 0.0

sphere_radius = float(input())
sphere_volume = (4.0/3.0)*pi*(sphere_radius)**3

print('Sphere volume: {:.2f}'.format(sphere_volume))
```

**Output:**

```
1
Sphere volume: 4.19
```